# 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT in two Nexus repositories of one group

Tags: maven, nexus, snapshot, maven-indexer

Say I have a "public" group in Nexus which contains two repositories "snapshotsA" and "snapshotsB". Both contain versions with the same Maven coordinates, like `com.something:artifact:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT`. How does Nexus resolve a SNAPSHOT reference? Does it look into both repositories to find the latest element? Or is it satisfied after finding the first one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For groups in Nexus Repository 2.x, we resolve the first match in the group ordering, unless some sort of Repository Routing or Repository Target rules prevent that from being matched (for example if you know bad versions of that component exist in that repository by not treating components immutably, etc...)

In Nexus Repository 3.x this is currently simpler as we have not implemented Repository Routing. The first match in the group ordering is what you would get back.

Comment: This means that if there is a version matching 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT in the first repository (in the group ordering), all others are ignored?

Answer (score 1):

Group repositories serve a list of repositories under the same URL. They fetch the `maven-metadata.xml` files from all the repositories they serve and create a merged representation of them. They also have a Lucene index via the [maven-indexer](https://github.com/apache/maven-indexer/) (which is a library contributed as OSS by Sonatype to Apache that allows a repository manager, or tool, such as an IDE, to work with this index of artifacts contained in the repository). The index of group repositories is also a merged representation of the indexes of each of the repositories in the group.

As far as I'm aware, for Nexus 2.x, the file system is the first place to try and, if it fails, the Lucene index is queried in order to resolve from the respective proxy repository's remote host.